# How do I take specific numbers from a column in R?

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a df that looks like this:

```
  columnA         B100              Score          Score2
    G01440100208022 10010208022          35            2
    G01330100208023 10010208023          61            4
    G01090100208024 10010208024          48            2
    G01007300129114 10730129114          13            1
    G62117300129121 10730129121          74            6
    G72007300129122 10730129122          63            4
```

and I would like to extract the first 4 numbers after `G0` if `columnA` begins with `G0`. For example, this would be `1440,1330,1090` for the first three rows.

If the column begins with G(number) such as the final row (G7). I would like to extract the first 5 numbers after G. For example this would be `62117, 72007`.

Does anyone know how I can easily do this? Ideally the final df would look like:

```
columnA         B100              Score          Score2      New
        G01440100208022 10010208022          35            2   1440 
        G01330100208023 10010208023          61            4   1330 
        G01090100208024 10010208024          48            2   1090
        G01007300129114 10730129114          13            1   1007
        G62117300129121 10730129121          74            6   62117
        G72007300129122 10730129122          63            4   72007
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option can be `case_when` for multiple conditions (though, in this case, there are other easier options)

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(New = case_when(str_detect(columnA, "^G0") ~ 
         str_sub(columnA, 3, 6), TRUE ~ str_sub(columnA,2, 6)))
#        columnA        B100 Score Score2   New
#1 G01440100208022 10010208022    35      2  1440
#2 G01330100208023 10010208023    61      4  1330
#3 G01090100208024 10010208024    48      2  1090
#4 G01007300129114 10730129114    13      1  1007
#5 G62117300129121 10730129121    74      6 62117
#6 G72007300129122 10730129122    63      4 72007
```

---

Or an easier option is to capture the 5 digits after the 'G' and then convert to `numeric` so that the 0s at the beginning will be dropped

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(New = as.integer( sub("^G(\\d{5}).*", "\\1", columnA)))
#        columnA        B100 Score Score2   New
#1 G01440100208022 10010208022    35      2  1440
#2 G01330100208023 10010208023    61      4  1330
#3 G01090100208024 10010208024    48      2  1090
#4 G01007300129114 10730129114    13      1  1007
#5 G62117300129121 10730129121    74      6 62117
#6 G72007300129122 10730129122    63      4 72007
```

---

Or simply using `base R`

```
as.integer( sub("^G(\\d{5}).*", "\\1", df1$columnA))
#[1]  1440  1330  1090  1007 62117 72007
```

Or with `substr`

```
as.integer(substr(df1$columnA, 2, 6))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(columnA = c("G01440100208022", "G01330100208023", 
"G01090100208024", "G01007300129114", "G62117300129121", "G72007300129122"
), B100 = c(10010208022, 10010208023, 10010208024, 10730129114, 
10730129121, 10730129122), Score = c(35L, 61L, 48L, 13L, 74L, 
63L), Score2 = c(2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am using Rstudio and it says that stringr is for 3.3 or newer though I just updated to newest Rstudio, do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: @Evan  I have `R 3.6.2` with `stringr` version `1.4.0`.  can you update your R  version